# How do I invalidate a Spring RestTemplate's currennt SSLSession?

Tags: spring, ssl, resttemplate

A long and very infuriating story short, I am using Spring RestTemplate to complete a series of RESTful queries against a poorly configured 3rd party SSL webserver, resulting in random SSL session timeouts from the server. The only factor that seems to make a difference is how powerful a CPU the service that uses the Rest Client running on. (so it will work great on a devloper's ThreadRipper, but will fail catastrophically on an AWS EC2 instance)

I've come to the conclusion that I need a way to invalidate the current SSLSession being used by a given RestTemplate. But how?

I am unable to fix the 3rd Party server, or even convince them that their SSL is configured incorrectly.